# Where to generate View?

Tags: design, performance

I plan to build a CRM for small companies. It is supposed to be a single-page application.

Now I am unsure where it is more efficient to convert the data to HTML. Should I rather do it on the server side to reduce the workload on the client and then send the HTML to render and insert it with `$(element).html(data)` or should I send just JSON to the client and let backbone.js do the rendering?

To make this question not just opinion based, I will add some data of the server, clients and the frameworks I plan to use.

#### Server

**Hardware**
Min. Raspberry PI 2

**OS**
Windows or Linux both recent

**Web Framework**
node.js with express and handlebars

#### Desktopclient

**Hardware**

- Desktop

  - CPU: i3 - i5 (2013)
  - RAM: 4GB - 8GB
  - Graphics: Integrated or OnBoard
- Mobile

  - iPhone 5 - 6+
  - iPad 4 - Air 2

**Browser**

- Desktop

  - Most recent IE, Firefox and Chrome
- Mobile

  - Safari

**Client frameworks**
backbone.js, jQuery, bootstrap and underscore.js

Comment: Do you need off-line capabilities?

Comment: @JeffO like `localStorage` etc? I need the `pushState` function for navigation. But I think that is it.

Comment: If it's a Single-Page application, it's done in the browser by definition.

Comment: @RobertHarvey why? Isn't the single page part only for no redirects? That is how I understood it by now ;)

Comment: See [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) for a brief, but detailed description.

Comment: So I am basically asking the wrong thing and should rather ask if an SPA is right here?